# Configure Spring Boot with two ports

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying configure an application in `Spring Boot` with two differents ports, but I haven't got still.
My first approximation has been with two controllers and I have defined a `@Bean` inside the two controller with `container.setPort(8080);`
And my second approximation has been add the actuator dependency and change the port of the management, but my application don't run. It shows:

```
Address already in use: bind
```

How can I confiure an application with two ports? I want one port for admin and the other port is for consults of my api.

Comment: Which of the following responses did you consider *the answer*?  Could you mark it as such when you get a chance?  Click on the flag next to this comment and mark this comment for deletion.  Thank you.

Answer (score 35):

As is has been mentioned before, `server.port` and `management.port` along with `management.context-path` properties could be set to make the embedded container to listen on different ports (management-related properties to access `Actuator` endpoints).

To listen on ports other than `server.port` and `management.port`:

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedTomcatConfiguration {

    @Value("${server.additionalPorts}")
    private String additionalPorts;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        Connector[] additionalConnectors = this.additionalConnector();
        if (additionalConnectors != null && additionalConnectors.length > 0) {
            tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(additionalConnectors);
        }
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector[] additionalConnector() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.additionalPorts)) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] ports = this.additionalPorts.split(",");
        List<Connector> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String port : ports) {
            Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
            connector.setScheme("http");
            connector.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port));
            result.add(connector);
        }
        return result.toArray(new Connector[] {});
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${appPort:8800}
  additionalPorts: 8881,8882
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(...)
@Import(EmbeddedTomcatConfiguration.class)
public Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}
```

I recently blogged about this topic at:

- [Configuring Tomcat to Listen on Multiple ports using Spring Boot](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/15/Configuring-Tomcat-to-Listen-on-Multiple-ports-using-Spring-Boot.html)

Comment: Just as addition, there is Spring Boot 2.0 modification - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554023/spring-boot-2-0-multiply-ports-listening?rq=1

Comment: How do you now differentiate
localhost:port1 -> serve index page for admin
localhost:port2 -> serve index page for other

Answer (score 8):

Since springboot 2, `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` mentioned in [ootero solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218348/1716570) is no longer available, so you should use either `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` or `TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory` according to your context.

The solution stays the same aside from the factory injection :

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    Connector[] additionalConnectors = this.additionalConnector();
    if (additionalConnectors != null && additionalConnectors.length > 0) {
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(additionalConnectors);
    }
    return tomcat;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To change Actuator management port you can use property

```
management.port=8081
```

See full list of properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

**Update:**
Actuator creates one more Embedded Tomcat(servlet container) instance in this case.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575595/spring-boot-with-endpoints-creates-two-tomcat-containers) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2798)

Comment: yes, i know, but is possible to do this: management.port =8081 and server.port=8080 ? and have two differents ports in the same application?7

Comment: server port is 8080 by default. 2 different ports mean 2 different sockets listening on different ports.

Comment: thank you, I know that is a posibility but we dont want have our admin application in the actuator port, we need a different port.

Answer (score 1):

To run 2 or more applications within a single project or change the default port, you can perform the action like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NewApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(NewApplication .class);
         app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "8083"));
         app.run(args);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If only one additional port is to be opened, the following is sufficient (Kotlin):

```
@Configuration
class AdditionalEndpointConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(PORT_PROPERTY)
    fun tomcatServletWebServerFactory(@Value("\${$PORT_PROPERTY}") additionalPort: Int) =
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory().apply {
            addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(
                Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol").apply {
                    scheme = "http"
                    port = additionalPort
                })
        }

    companion object {
        const val PORT_PROPERTY = "server.additional.port"
    }
}
```