# spring boot 2.0 listening on multiple ports

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I need to have 2 ports listening in embedded tomcat - lets say 8443 (https) and 8081 (http).

With spring boot `1.5.3.RELEASE` I did something like:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory =
                        (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;

                Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
                connector.setPort(httpPort);
                containerFactory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And it was fine. Now I'm trying to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` `2.0.0.M6` and the following classes cannot be found:

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer`
 `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`
 `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`

So I'm looking for a way to accept connections on multiple ports. How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.0.0 M1 [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#embedded-containers-package-structure]) state that:

> the embedded containers package structure has been refactored quite
>   extensively. EmbeddedServletContainer has been renamed to WebServer
>   and the org.springframework.boot.context.embedded package has been
>   relocated to org.springframework.boot.web.embedded. For instance, if
>   you were customizing the embedded Tomcat container using the
>   TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory callback interface, you should
>   now use TomcatServletWebServerFactory.

From the Spring Boot source code, starting with commit [67556ba8ea](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/67556ba8eaf22a352b03fe197a0c452f695835a6):

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer` was moved to `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory`

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`was moved to `org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer`

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` was moved to `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory`