# How to configure in Spring Boot 2 (w/ WebFlux) two ports for HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Can anybody tell me how 2 ports (for HTTP and HTTPS) can be configured when using Spring Boot 2 and WebFlux? Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

This [isn't directly supported by Spring Boot 2 yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12035).

But, you may be able to get it to work in a couple of ways.

By default, Spring Boot WebFlux uses Netty. If you are already configured [for ssl](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/), then Spring Boot will start up and open port 8443 (or whatever you have configured).

Then, to add 8080, you can do:

```
@Autowired
HttpHandler httpHandler;

WebServer http;

@PostConstruct
public void start() {
    ReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory(8080);
    this.http = factory.getWebServer(this.httpHandler);
    this.http.start();
}

@PreDestroy
public void stop() {
    this.http.stop();
}
```

Which is a bit clunky since your https configuration is in one spot (application.yml) and your http configuration is in Java config, but I have tested this myself with a toy application. Not sure how robust of a solution it is, though.

Another option that may work is to try the equivalent of other suggestions, but use the reactive version of the class, which is `TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory`. I'm not aware of any way to provide more than one connector for it, but you could possibly override its `getWebServer` method:

```
@Bean
TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory twoPorts() {
    return new TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory(8443) {
        @Override
        public WebServer getWebServer(HttpHandler httpHandler) {
           // .. copy lines from parent class
           // .. and add your own Connector, similar to how tutorials describe for servlet-based support
        }
    }
}
```

Also, a bit messy, and I have not tried that approach myself.

Of course, keep track of [the ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12035) so you know when Spring Boot 2 provides official support.

Comment: Unfortunately so far only reasonable way doing this!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions listed in the link provided by jojo_berlin [(here's the link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218348/3161062).  Instead of using his EmbeddedTomcatConfiguration class though, use this below

```java
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {

    @Value("${server.http.port}")
    private int httpPort;

    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking about a WebFlux-based app, not Servlet-based.

Comment: Well - it was helping me so thanks for providing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can define a second connector as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218348/3161062) . So you can define a https connector as your default and an additional HTTP Connector

Comment: The answer you point to won't work as is with Spring Boot 2, since the embedded containers package structure has been [refactored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554861/5873923).

Comment: The linked instructions are to build a servlet-based application, not webflux-based.