# Spring Cloud Gateway listen to both HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

How can I configure a Spring Cloud Gateway server to accept both HTTP and HTTPS connections?

I have SSL configured to port 443 on the Gateway server. I also want to accept HTTP requests on port 80. I know how to do this with a standard Spring Boot application running Tomcat, but I need to know how to configure the Netty server that Gateway uses.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently spring cloud gateway uses webflux which does not directly support it, but there are some ways:
[How to configure in Spring Boot 2 (w/ WebFlux) two ports for HTTP and HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221194/how-to-configure-in-spring-boot-2-w-webflux-two-ports-for-http-and-https)

Also waiting for a real solution:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12035

Answer (score 2):

Spring CLoud Gateway Documentation shows the solution:
[7. TLS / SSL](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__tls_ssl.html)

Gateway routes can be routed to both http and https backends. If routing to a https backend then the Gateway can be configured to trust all downstream certificates with the following configuration:

application.yml.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. What this configuration allows you to do is to call downstream services that are both http and https by trusting all downstream certificates. The poster wants the gateway to be accessible using both http on port 80 and https on port 443.