# Spring Boot 2, Java 10 and QueryDsl - Errors during migration from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, querydsl

Migrating a Spring Boot 1.5 application (which was initially generated via JHipster 4.13.3, with Java 8 and QueryDsl 4.1.4) to Spring Boot 2.x (using Java 10).

Using QueryDsl worked in 1.5, now with 2.x I get the following Build Errors, like:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project webfit: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] .../WebConfigurer.java:[15,58] package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow does not exist
[ERROR] .../WebConfigurer.java:[35,66] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
[ERROR] .../WebConfigurer.java:[68,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer
[ERROR] location: ...config.WebConfigurer
[ERROR] .../WebConfigurer.java:[93,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer
[ERROR] location: class ...config.WebConfigurer
[ERROR] .../WebConfigurer.java:[14,1] package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded does not exist
[ERROR] .../ApplicationWebXml.java:[5,44] package org.springframework.boot.web.support does not exist
[ERROR] .../ApplicationWebXml.java:[11,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class SpringBootServletInitializer
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[5,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] location: package org.springframework.data.querydsl
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[14,92] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[7,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] location: package org.springframework.data.querydsl
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[15,90] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] .../service/MailService.java:[16,29] package org.thymeleaf.spring4 does not exist
[ERROR] .../service/MailService.java:[41,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SpringTemplateEngine
[ERROR] location: class ...service.MailService
[ERROR] .../service/MailService.java:[44,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SpringTemplateEngine
[ERROR] location: class ...service.MailService
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[7,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] location: package org.springframework.data.querydsl
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[15,110] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] ...App.java:[11,1] package org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure does not exist
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[8,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] location: package org.springframework.data.querydsl
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[16,95] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[5,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] location: package org.springframework.data.querydsl
[ERROR] ...Repository.java:[14,90] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class QueryDslPredicateExecutor
[ERROR] ...App.java:[25,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class MetricFilterAutoConfiguration
[ERROR] ...App.java:[25,74] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration
```

How to solve these?

In the POM I use:

```
...
<jhipster-dependencies.version>2.0.2</jhipster-dependencies.version>
<spring-boot.version>2.0.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
...
```

Interestingly in Eclipse I see in Maven Dependencies the usage of 2.0.1 (but I specified 2.0.2) for example:

```
...
spring-boot-starter-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-cache-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
...
jhipster-1.3.0.jar
...
hibernate-jcache-5.2.16.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar
...
querydsl-apt-4.1.4.jar
querydsl-codegen-4.1.4.jar
...
```

Not sure which other Dependencies to list here which might be of interest to the problem.

Also to mention, that we don't use in our POM the Spring Boot Starter Parent POM, like it is usually generated via Spring Initializr:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Also, what is the right usage:

```
<java.version>10</java.version>

or 

<java.version>1.10</java.version>
```

One last mention:
In Eclipse it says "JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]", I don't know how it comes that there is "J2SE-1.5", before it was 1.8 as far as I remember. In the Preferences under "Installed JREs" it is "java-10-oracle (default)" at location "/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle".

If I open the JRE System Library, it says to everything there "/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/...".

Perhaps because of the "J2SE-1.5" I get some Java Problems in Eclipse, like:

```
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

If I navigate to this Java Problem, it is the line:

```
...
Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can somebody explain, whey I got -4 on this issue post?

Comment: Probably because your post does not show much effort on your part about solving this issue. You should have first migrated from SB 1.5 to 2.0, solved the package and class renaming issues (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554861/5873923) for instance), then upgraded to Java 10.