# Spring Boot Multiple Ports?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, port, application.properties

How can I have a spring boot web application running on multiple ports?
for example 8080 and 80

how can I achive this?
application.properties

```
server.port=8080, 80
```

Comment: One (spring boot) application only listens on one port. If you want a spring boot application to listen to 2 ports, start 2 up with server.port=8080 and the other one on server.port=80 i.e. seperate application.properties files.

Comment: It is discussed in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357135/configure-spring-boot-with-two-ports/69190413)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of running multiple applications, you can add listeners. For example, if you use undertow :

```
@Configuration
public class PortConfig {

    @Value("${server.http.port}")
    private int httpPort;

    @Bean
    public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Undertow.Builder builder) {
                builder.addHttpListener(httpPort, "0.0.0.0");
            }

        });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I have use this to listen to http port AND https port.

For Tomcat you will find the same kind of configurations :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html

Comment: It is dicussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357135/configure-spring-boot-with-two-ports/69190413

Answer (score -1):

You can run it by using below mentioned command:

**mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8080**

**mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8081**

Just change the port number and run it on another terminal. At a same time you can run the multiple instances of same spring boot app.

Now one spring boot app is running on 2 ports, one is on 8080 and another one is on 8081.

Comment: The question is about running multiple ports in single app,

Comment: These commands are also running a single app on multiple ports @krishnaTelgave

Comment: those two command has to run separately so will run as two different apps.