# Reduce # of threads created when a Spring Boot-based service is listening on many ports?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is probably a rather peculiar question.  I am using Spring Boot 2.0.2 with the default Tomcat container.  In order to set up a test in our QA environment that simulates many servers, I would like to set up a Spring Boot-based REST service that listens on a very large number of ports simultaneously.  I'm able to do this using the technique previously described in in another SO post ([Configure Spring Boot with two ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357135/configure-spring-boot-with-two-ports)) which basically adds connectors using TomcatServletWebServerFactory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors().

The difficulty is that a large number of threads seem to be created for each additional port activated; some empirical measurements show the total to be 17 + (15 * number of ports).  This means listening on 250 ports result in 3767 threads created and 500 ports result in 7517 threads created and I would like to go somewhat beyond that number.  The test program used to take the above measurements is the bare minimum to bring up a Spring service and there is no code that creates threads explicitly so insofar, as I know, all of those threads were created by Spring/Tomcat.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Spring that doesn't use so many threads per active port?  Would an alternate container like Jetty be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the embedded tomcat container properties in spring boot configuration file and set the appropriate numbers for these properties to limit the threads created by Tomcat container -

```
    server.tomcat.max-threads=200 # Maximum amount of worker threads.
    server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=10 # Minimum amount of worker threads.
```

Comment: I appreciate the response!  I did make the suggested adjustments but, unfortunately, the thread count remained the same.