# How to deploy spring boot 2.7.3 application in diferrent port numbers

Tags: spring

I have implemented **spring boot 2.7.3** version application. Now I want to deploy the application in different port numbers.  So I used a maven build... goal like **spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=7878** as we use in **spring boot 1.x** but it is getting deployed in default port defined in application.properties or 8080 only.

Is there any alternate property/goal defined in **spring boot 2.7.3** for deploying multiple times with different port numbers?

I found in case of profiles as below:
For Spring Boot 2.x+ run has been renamed to spring-boot.run and run.profiles has been renamed to spring-boot.run.profiles

Comment: This seems like a good answer to your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357135/configure-spring-boot-with-two-ports

Answer (score 1):

If you have embedded tomcat server.

You can simply use `server.port=8082` in your `application.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks for this but every time when deploying with a new port number the application.properties has to change.